.NET 8.0 / EF Core : DateTime Query "Z" issue
I'm using EF Core with .NET 8. I'm trying to query a row in the database via date, but when query generated it has "Z" at the end.
Here is the query generated by EF Core:
-- @__filter_OrderStatus_0='1'
-- @__startOfDay_1='2024-08-18T00:00:00.0000000Z' (DbType = DateTime)
-- @__endOfDay_2='2024-08-18T23:59:59.9999999Z' (DbType = DateTime)
-- @__filter_VehicleId_3='d856c3f9-b274-4e8b-8089-329262313766'
SELECT o."Id", o."ActualTakeDate", o."CreatedDate", o."CustomOrder", o."CustomerId", o."Deleted", o."DeletedDate", o."DeliverDate", o."DoneDate", o."EstimatedOrderTotal", o."Note", o."OrderNumber", o."ReceiptId", o."Status", o."Subtotal", o."TakeDate", o."UpdatedDate", o."VehicleId", t."Id", t."Address", t."AreaId", t."CreatedDate", t."CustomerNumber", t."CustomerSettingsId", t."Deleted", t."DeletedDate", t."FullName", t."Location", t."PhoneNumber", t."UpdatedDate", t0."Id", t0."CreatedDate", t0."Deleted", t0."DeletedDate", t0."Name", t0."OrderId", t0."Price", t0."Qty", t0."Unit", t0."UpdatedDate", t0."Value"
FROM "Orders" AS o
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT c."Id", c."Address", c."AreaId", c."CreatedDate", c."CustomerNumber", c."CustomerSettingsId", c."Deleted", c."DeletedDate", c."FullName", c."Location", c."PhoneNumber", c."UpdatedDate"
    FROM "Customers" AS c
    WHERE NOT (c."Deleted")
) AS t ON o."CustomerId" = t."Id"
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT o0."Id", o0."CreatedDate", o0."Deleted", o0."DeletedDate", o0."Name", o0."OrderId", o0."Price", o0."Qty", o0."Unit", o0."UpdatedDate", o0."Value"
    FROM "OrderEntries" AS o0
    WHERE NOT (o0."Deleted")
) AS t0 ON o."Id" = t0."OrderId"
WHERE NOT (o."Deleted") AND o."Status" = @__filter_OrderStatus_0 AND o."TakeDate" >= @__startOfDay_1 AND o."TakeDate" <= @__endOfDay_2 AND o."VehicleId" = @__filter_VehicleId_3
ORDER BY o."Id", t."Id"

If I remove the "Z"s in the params query works fine.
SQL Result Screenshot
This is how I make the query
var startOfDay = DateTime.SpecifyKind(filter.TakeDate.Value.Date, DateTimeKind.Utc);
var endOfDay = DateTime.SpecifyKind(filter.TakeDate.Value.Date.AddDays(1).AddTicks(-1), DateTimeKind.Utc);

expression = expression.Merge(e => e.TakeDate >= startOfDay && e.TakeDate <= endOfDay);

What am I missing?
I tried what I sent above.

Try to specify endOfDay as var endOfDay = startOfDay.AddDays(1); and Merge as expression = expression.Merge(e => e.TakeDate >= startOfDay && e.TakeDate < endOfDay);

Can you please specify the problem? Do you get an error? Incorrect results?

Also as a wild guess - try looking at this answer maybe it is related

@GuruStron i was getting empty results

Turns out my Column data types was "timestampz".
Solved by adding this to program.cs
AppContext.SetSwitch("Npgsql.EnableLegacyTimestampBehavior", true);


So my suggestion/guess worked?)
